# Как правильно написать процедуру инициализации для структуры

Tags: golang

Имею такую структуру на GoLang, исходя из данных JSON

```
type Account struct {
    User struct {
        Login       string `json:"login"`
        Password    string `json:"password"`
        VillageName string `json:"VillageName"`
        Vert        int    `json:"vert"`
        Gor         int    `json:"gor"`
        Weater      int    `json:"weater"`
        Resources   []int  `json:"resources"`
        Buildings   []struct {
            Vert          int `json:"vert"`
            Gor           int `json:"gor"`
            BuildingID    int `json:"building_id,omitempty"`
            BuildingLevel int `json:"building_level"`
            Building      int `json:"building,omitempty"`
        } `json:"buildings"`
    } `json:"user"`
}
```

Нужна помощь в написании процедуры инициализации, потому что при создании, все поля должны быть заполнены не nil. И не до конца понимаю как быть с инициализацией других вложенных структур. Объясните пожалуйста, в GoLang новичок

Comment: Можете использовать пакет, аналогичный [этому](https://github.com/creasty/defaults), либо написать функцию NewAccount, которая будет создавать объект с заданными значениями по умолчанию.

Comment: ¿при чем тут С++?

Comment: ни одно поле не может быть nil. только примитивы ссылочного типа будут nil

Answer (score 1):

В `go` нет понятия конструктора. Но сложился обычай называеть функции, создающие структуры `Name` как `NewName`

То есть вам нужно написать функцию `NewAccount`, которая инициализирует поля структуры. Набор аргументов зависит от вас. Просто имейте в виду, что в `go` нет перегрузки функций, поэтому если вам нужен конструктор по умолчанию, то его следует назвать `DefaultAccount` (нужно сказать, что это правило именования менее распространено, чем `New`).